# add svg and use elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I wanna add a icon using only pure javascript. The icon is local on my network and in html it looks like this :

```
 <svg class="pictogram pictogram-checkmark">

          <use xlink:href="/cdn/svg/v18/svg-icons.svg#checkmark" href="/cdn/svg/v18/svg-icons.svg#checkmark"></use>
      </svg>
```

How do I transform this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have a current icon with this html code. I want to change it but using only pure javascript. The icon i wanna use has the same code snip, just some name changes.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that you have somewhere an root svg element where you keep your definitions (the first svg element in this case) here is how create a new svg element and a use element to reuse the path:

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
// create a new svg element
let svg = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'svg');
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 24 24");
// append the new svg element
where.appendChild(svg);
// create a new use element
let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#checkmark');
// append the new svg element to the svg element
svg.appendChild(use);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
#root{position:absolute;left:-10em;}
#where svg{width:24px; height:24px;}
#where svg use{fill:green;}
```

```html
<svg id="root" width='0' height='0' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>check</title>
    <path id="checkmark" d='M9 16.17l-4.17-4.17-1.42 1.41 5.59 5.59 12-12-1.41-1.41z'></path>
</svg>

<p id="where"></p>
```

Alternatively for a checkmark you may use glyphs: `&#x2713;`: ✓ or `&#x2714;`:  ✔